# Urlopen hangs with site

Tags: python, urlopen

I'm using `urlopen` to read a site but it hangs in my program.
But when I'm testing from terminal and python interpreter it works fine.
The code is this:

```
page = urlopen ("http://mangafox.me/directory/").read ()
print ('soup')
# soup = BeautifulSoup (urlopen ("http://www.mangafox.me/directory/").read (), 'html.parser')
print ("soup")
manga_img = soup.findAll ('a', {'class' : 'manga_img'}, limit=None)
```

Comment: then there's something in your program, show us how you use this and what's around

Comment: It was running on a different thread, when I moved it to the main application thread it worked! But now i get a lot of Http Error.